# The function of "would" in the following sentences

Tags: modal-verbs

> The whole class was laughing as if they would die. The German teacher
> tried in vain to stop their noise. But they would not listen to her.

Question 1:

> But they would not listen to her.

What is the function of "would" here? I know that would may imply future in the past tense. But that is obvously nonsense in this sentence.
Why wasn't it written "But they did not listen to her."?

Question 2:

Are the following sentences equal:

> "as if they would die" = "as if they was going to die" ?

What means by "they were laughing as if they would die"?

Comment: (1) One of the meanings of _would not_ is _refused to_. (2) Yes, it means 'as if they _were_ going to die'.

Comment: Past time "would" is used here to express **volition**, i.e. expressing unwillingness or refusal. Yes, the two examples you give in 2  have the same meaning.

Comment: What @BillJ said. Note that "volition" is the only reason the cited example differs from *But they **did** not listen to her*. In both cases they didn't listen, but using ***would** not* emphasises that they *deliberately* refused (not listening wasn't by "oversight" - it was an explicitly chosen action).